# iPhone app non-app store (safari) purchases

Tags: iphone, safari, integration

I wanted to develop an iphone magazine application which will allow a user to purchase single issues or subscriptions through safari with a user id instead of the app store. What does my website require to be able to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

It won't require anything special. Just a way to collect money from users (CreditCard, PayPal, Google Checkout support), a user database, a registration mechanism and you are done.   If I were you, I would reconsidering selling your content through AppStore with IN-APP purchases, because you will have immediate access to all technical stuff I just mentioned and a huge instant potential client you will have to build yourself otherwise.

Hope it helps.